# Prolog: How to check only one occurrence of a variable within a list, in a number of facts?

Tags: prolog

I have been able to check if a variable occurs more than once. I am struggling however to do this if the variable is in a list.

So in my example, I want to check to make sure that any ingredient is only present in one food item. When they are apart of a list however, I am struggling to work out how to recursively check each one of the ingredients.

Any help would be much appreciated!

What I have at the moment, which only successfully checks if the entire lists are the same:

```
food(salad,[rocket,celery]).
food(pizza,[base,sauce,toppings]).

check_only_one_ingredient :- \+ (food(A,[X]), food(B,[X]), A \= B;).
```

Then I would call:

```
?- check_only_one_ingredient.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost done

```
check_only_one_ingredient :-
 \+ ( food(F1, L1),
      food(F2, L2),
      F1 \= F2,
      member(X, L1),
      member(X, L2)
    ).
```